# Delphi: How to open Batch file in Thread (Windows Service)

Tags: delphi, windows-services, shellexecute, tthread

I wrote a Windows Application and now I want to transform it into a Windows Service. In my Windows Service Program I have a thread which should open a batch file. Normally I open batch files with Shell Execute:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PWideChar('myPath'), nil,nil, SW_Hide);
```

But I can not use SW_Hide in my thread. Is there any other way opening a batch file in a thread or am I using the correct approach?

Comment: It's always wrong to use ShellExecute here. To create a process use CreateProcess.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any other way opening a Batch file in a Thread

You can open a batch file by the following command line:

```
cmd.exe /c mybatch.bat arg1 arg2 arg3
```

And you can start this from your thread using Windows API `CreateProcess`.

Comment: Wouldn't that show Command prompt window? Based on OP question I have a feeling that he would like to execute batch file in background without showing any window.

Comment: @SilverWarior: One of the options in CreateProcess is to create the window hidden, but if OP can't use SW_HIDE in ShellExecute, I wonder if he can use it in CreateProcess...

Comment: @HeartWare He didn't told why he cannot use in ShellExecute, but for sure it can be used in CreateProcess. Maybe he can't since his application is a service? I wonder if his problem is not the shell which probably is not there for a service.

Comment: @fpiette thanks for your answer. So I wrote a normal windows application and now I want to transform it into a service. After I embedded the shell Api I had no error. Only SW_Hide was underlined. I will try Crate Process now :)